# Botones en ActionBar de Android

Tags: android, android-studio, toolbar

estoy creando una aplicación y necesito poner botones en el `ActionBar` y ya lo hice pero no se como poner imágenes en los botones y solo sale texto (ver imagen) la cuestión es que en XML si se hacerlo pero en este caso no puedo usar XML solo Java ¿alguna idea de como hacerlo solo con Java?

Código que estoy usando (también esta el del menú overflow):

```
android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchview;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
   menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Notificar");
   menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Test de velocidad");
   menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Salir");
   menu.add(0,3,3,"Refrescar").setActionView(searchview).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
   menu.add(0,4,4,"Ayuda").setActionView(searchview).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
   return true;
}
```

[image: imagen de actionbar]

Comment: Gracias por acomodar el código, tenia un reguero tremendo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que ya tienes los iconos en `res->drawable`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Notificar");
    menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Test de velocidad");
    menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Salir");
    menu.add(0, 3, 3, "Refrescar").setActionView(searchview).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    menu.add(0, 4, 4, "Ayuda").setActionView(searchview).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

   // Agrega esto
   // Menú para Notificar
   menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_icon);

  // Menú para test de velocidad
   menu.getItem(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_speedtest_icon);
   ...

   // Eso es para que visualice los iconos en el overflow menu
   if(menu instanceof MenuBuilder) {
        MenuBuilder m = (MenuBuilder) menu;
        m.setOptionalIconsVisible(true);
    }

   return true;
}
```

El parámetro `0` de `getItem()` te indica el indice del menú, por ejemplo para notificar es `0`, para test de velocidad es `1`, etc.

**Editado** Agregué unas lineas de código más, la razón es que investigando me di cuenta que los menús `overflow` aparecen sin iconos.

Comment: Si me di cuenta pero muchas gracias funciona a la perfección